# Delete Query deletes all records without leaving the original ones when duplicates are detected

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have two tables, tbl_NTE and tbl_PAH. There are records in tbl_PAH that is already available in tbl_NTE that is why I created an append query to automatically transfer and update some records which as a result causes duplicates every time I click the save button because the save button triggers the append query query.

I want to run a query where all the data with duplicates are deleted and just leave the original ones.

I created a delete query and typed the criteria:-

```
 In (SELECT [CaseIDNo] 
 FROM [tbl_PAH] As Tmp GROUP BY [CaseIDNo] 
 HAVING Count(*)>1 )
```

I've also tried Last, First, Max and Group By as criteria but all it does it delete all the records as well.

```
 In (SELECT DISTINCTROW tbl_PAH.CaseIDNo
 FROM tbl_PAH
 GROUP BY tbl_PAH.CaseIDNo
 HAVING (((tbl_PAH.CaseIDNo) In (SELECT Last(tbl_PAH.CaseIDNo) AS 
 LastOfCaseIDNo FROM tbl_PAH Group By tbl_PAH.CaseIDNo HAVING 
 (((Count(tbl_PAH.CaseIDNo))>1));)));)
```

Here is the other one I've tried but also deletes the whole records of duplicates without leaving the original one.

```
 DELETE tbl_PAH.CaseIDNo
 FROM tbl_PAH
 WHERE (((tbl_PAH.CaseIDNo) In (SELECT DISTINCTROW tbl_PAH.CaseIDNo
 FROM tbl_PAH
 GROUP BY tbl_PAH.CaseIDNo;)));
```

and when I run it, all the duplicates are deleted without leaving the original ones. Any idea on how I can work this out?

I've already set the Unique Records to Yes. I set the index to Yes (Duplicates Ok) to have no error while automatically appending the records to other tables but as a result, duplicates are created. Any help on deleting the duplicates with the criteria "When a record has duplicates in terms of CaseIDNo, the duplicates will be deleted leaving only the original record." I am a newbie at MS Access 2010 that is why I am still learning. I am using Microsoft Access 2010. Thank you in advance to those who will answer.

Comment: Does your table have an autonumber field or other unique identifier?

Comment: Hi @ErikvonAsmuth. My table has an autonumber fields which is "id" but I only created it to allow duplicates in CaseIDNo which is the important one and must have no duplicates. Because is order to append the records without encountering any problems, one way I discovered is to allow duplicates then just create a delete query to delete them. But now I am encountering a problem where when the database detected a duplicate, all the duplicates will be deleted without leaving the original record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query to delete all duplicate records where ID is not the minimal value of ID. Since ID is a unique column, that should leave the originals in place.

Note that I've refactored your first condition from an `IN` to an `EXISTS`, because those are often faster and more reliable.

```
DELETE tbl_PAH.CaseIDNo
FROM tbl_PAH t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_PAH s WHERE s.CaseIDNo = t.CaseIDNo HAVING COUNT(s.CaseIDNo) > 1) 
AND  t.ID <> (SELECT Min(s2.ID) FROM tbl_PAH s2 WHERE t.CaseIDNo = s2.CaseIDNo)
```